# calculate reserved ip address based on mac address

Tags: ip-address, dhcp-server, mac-address, isc-dhcp

Is it possible to calculate ip address based on mac address for isc-dhcp server?

For example:
'aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:x' => '10.10.10.x'

I have following in dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

  class "v" {
    match if substring (hardware, 0, 14) = "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA";
    }

  pool {
    range 10.10.10.101 10.10.10.200;
    deny unknown-clients;
    allow members of "v";
    fixed-address = concat('10.10.10.', substring (hardware, 15, 2));
    }
}
```

`fixed-address` directive is misplaced (have to be in `host` closure only), so I have error. Any workarounds exists?

Comment: There is no guarantee that there won't be any collisions for this method (it you can configure dhcpd to do this at all). Having collisions is even quite likely (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: mac addresses are generated for virtual machines. And i have guarantee that no collisions appear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this with ISC dhcpd (since `fixed-address` can only appear within a `host` clause).

Couldn't you get the same behaviour by generating a sequence of `host` clauses with the required MAC and IP addresses? I admit that I'm struggling to imagine a situation where this setup would be useful though.